# How do I configure Brunch.io to copy the index.js file from app/ to public/

Tags: javascript, brunch

Brunch is currently building my app and combining the css/js from the app and /app/assets folder but it doesn't copy the index.js file from the root of the app folder.
This is the index file which should become index.html inside the public folder.

I cannot work out how to config Brunch to do this. Any ideas?

Current Config: http://jsbin.com/lakapaxalamo/1

Folder Structure:
[image]

Comment: please post your current directory structure and config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index.html should be inside `app/assets`

Comment: Turns out that this was the right answer, Sorry for the delay in accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin, which will also optimize your HTML output: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pages-brunch